# Test Explorer does not group by Test Herarichy / Namespace using NUnit in VS 2017

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-test-runner

i have been using NUnit with Visual Studio 2017 and its working fine until my test cases grouped wrongly in test explorer

[image]

i have Code herarichy like 
Project Name > Component.PDF.Tests
Classes Name > PDFDOcument
Classes Name > FormField
Classes Name > Attachment

i have created all test methods under different classes but when i group by name space or test herarichy, i was expecting it will be grouped under Class name but above image shows most of the test cases comes under project name

Some of the test comes under Clases but all others moved to Parent namespace even though all of the classes and their tests defined in same way

- Envrioment: VS 2017
- Test Framework : NUnit 3.0
- Test Adapter : NUnit Adapter

has any one face this issue ? or i misunderstood something 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: I believe you need to explain a bit more about **what** is wrong, make it more explicit. Boil it down to something simple to explain, and show images of that, and even some code snippets for what is being shown.   Also, ensure you run the latest versions of VS and NUnit/Adapter, there are changes in them all.

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm i m using latest version of NUnit and Nunit Adapter regarding what is wrong. i  m getting 37 test cases under Components.PDF.Tests where as these 37 tests are defined under PDFDocumentFIxture or other classes that marked as Text Fixture . This issue m compalining is about why test comes under project name rather than under class name

Answer (score 0):

By default, VS groups Project, Namespace, Class - and then the test methods, as shown in the image below:
[image]

You can change this whatever way you want, by editing the grouping.  The default grouping will look like shown below.
[image]

So if you want just to group by class name, remove the others.

This is with VS 2019.  With VS 2017 you have something they call Show Test Hierarchy, and it is defined to work the same way,  Project - Namespace - Class and then the test methods.

If you disable that one (1 - below), you can change the Group by to only show "by class" (2-below).

[image]

and you end up with:
[image]

Comment: i have already tried that but it didnot worked , only difference in your example and mine is that i m using test data that that can be 1 or multiple . May be thats causing the issue :(

Comment: Can you add some code fractions to repro your situation ?

Comment: Images will work or you want working code repo to reproduce the issue

Comment: ok i will get it for you , just a side note i have instsalled AxoCover extension and it showed all test cases as expected in its viewer.